# Making Related Models Optional

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a form where a user can enter a location address as well as the utility companies that provide service to that address. The Utility data is associated to the building:

```
Location hasMany Utility
```

Solely within the context of the utility, the `name` field is required so there's validation indicating as much. Within the context of a location, though, any utility information is optional. The user can choose not to enter that data when entering a location which would simply indicate that they don't want to associate the location with any or all of the utility companies we track.

Using the `FormHelper`, though, the validation is detected and the field gets marked as required. I want to retain that validation for the instances where utility data is being entered independently, but remove the required indicator on the location form.

I know I can hack this in any number of ways (e.g. removing the `required` class via javascript, etc.), but I'm wondering if there's a clean way to do this using the Cake API. I haven't seen anything obvious, so I'm hoping someone else has been here and found a clean, simple solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Haven't tested it; but you could perhaps try using the `fieldList` parameter for the `validates()` method... see [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1182/Validating-Data-from-the-Controller). Might not work with associated data however ~

Answer (score 1):

You can either ask the user how many utilities they want to add before creating the form, or you can add the Utility record inputs dynamically using js (the later is more work to do, and not as error-proof as the former).

An example of the view (if you want to do it in 1 view):

```
if (empty($this->data){
  // a form to ask how many utility records the users want to create.
}else{
  // generate the form based on user input.
}
```

I assume you know what to do in the controller.

Comment: Thus bypassing the FormHelper and giving me total control over the `required` class, it seems. Also a "hack" I was considering. I was hoping that there was a way to tell the `Utility` model to disable validation for the request that draws the form. Maybe I can just modify the `$validates` property directly...

Comment: no, you still use the formhelper to generate the form. You just know how many records for Utility to create when creating the form.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to the form element that are optionnal, and use that class to override the "required" indicator.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the hacks I'm considering, but I was hoping that there was an API I didn't know about to make this cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is a Cake solution, use the error param

```
$this->Form->input('Model.field', array('error' => false));
```

[To disable error message output set the error key to false.](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1390/Automagic-Form-Elements#options-error-1401)